# Migrating a websites' knowledgebase to PostgreSQL Database for search querying

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, database-migration

I've been tasked to create a search function for a websites' knowledgebase (which is stored in a github repo). I'm only really familiar with building databases with Django, so I'm having trouble understanding how I'm supposed to upload a bunch of html files to the database and query them with postgres. Any pointers on how the database can be structured. I've heard that html files can be stored in a text field, but how are the columns structured, does each page get its' own row, etc? and how can I do this with a fairly large knowledge base without having to manually upload each file?

The db hosting platform I am using has a migration utility that says

> Uploading will accept data in any of three forms, plain text (SQL), tar archives (uncompressed), or PostgreSQL's own compressed 'custom' format.

That's assuming the database is already structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've heard that html files can be stored in a text field, but how are the columns structured, does each page get its' own row, etc?

Storing html in a column is perfectly acceptable. If you're storing the html in a column, then each new page requires a new row.

> and how can I do this with a fairly large knowledge base without having to manually upload each file?

You just said the hosting provider permits "PostgreSQL's own compressed 'custom' format". So install PostgreSQL locally. Get it all up and working. Insert every page locally. Then you can upload to the hosting provider using `pg_dump --format=c` which is not just a single action, but compressed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Evan! One more question: is there some way to strip the pages of the html tags and such, so they are not returned in the search results?

Comment: Use [`HTML::Strip`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Strip) or the like. You may also want to do Full Text Search on the stripped text.